# "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to add JSON column to the table in MySQL databse and I am getting this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NULL' at line 1".

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to run something like

```
CREATE TABLE t (j JSON NULL);
```

MariaDB up to and including 10.2 does **not** support JSON *data type*. MariaDB supports [JSON **functions**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions/). The data is supposed to be stored in ordinary string columns (`TEXT`, `VARCHAR` etc.).

Comment: I am using MySQL and not MariaDB

Comment: Yes, you are using MariaDB. The error message that you quoted suggests that. Note "to your **MariaDB** server" part.

Comment: So how can I use MySQL in phpstorm?

Comment: Perhaps phpstorm installed MariaDB?  Perhaps phpstorm noticed that MySQL or MariaDB was already installed and accepted it?  `<opinion>`3rd party software often causes more trouble/confusion than benefit`</opinion>`.